# Oenone and Eno Zero - names based on numbers or what?

Tags: name-significance, mortal-engines, philip-reeve

In the *Mortal Engines* series by Philip Reeve, a major character in later instalments is Oenone Zero, a person whose first name I immediately noticed is an anagram of *one one*. At some point it's revealed that she had a brother called Eno, an anagram of *one*.

**What's with all the numbers in these character names?** Does it signify anything related to her character that her name is almost 110, or is it just a family trend that makes the character somehow memorable? (When writing this question, I didn't remember that there was a Greek mythological character called Oenone, but I still hold that the numbers thing in *Mortal Engines* can't be a coincidence, with Zero and Eno as well.)

Comment: Oenone is also a nymph in Greek mythology.  Paris was shacking up with her when the goddesses came to him to get a ruling about the apple, and he dumped her for Helen.

Comment: @Mary Ah, I'd forgotten that, thanks! I think my question is still valid though - even if Oenone is more than just an anagram of numbers, there's also Zero and Eno, which is surely too much for coincidence.

Comment: I don't know the books but "one one zero" immediately made me think of binary. Could that be relevant?